# Crash on copy paste on xiaomi devices

Tags: android, crash, copy-paste, poco, xiaomi

i am facing a issue that when user trying to copy and paste on poco and redmi devices app crashes. giving the stacktrace.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: miui.security.appcompatibility.AppCompatibilityManager
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:379)
        at com.miui.appcompatibility.b.b(Unknown Source:7)
        at com.miui.appcompatibility.b.a(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.miui.appcompatibility.b.a(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.miui.appcompatibility.g.a$a.a(Unknown Source:12)
        at com.miui.appcompatibility.g.a$a.doInBackground(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at
```

java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: miui.security.appcompatibility.AppCompatibilityManager
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454) 
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:379) 
at com.miui.appcompatibility.b.b(Unknown Source:7) 
at com.miui.appcompatibility.b.a(Unknown Source:0) 
at com.miui.appcompatibility.b.a(Unknown Source:4) 
at com.miui.appcompatibility.g.a$a.a(Unknown Source:12) 
at com.miui.appcompatibility.g.a$a.doInBackground(Unknown Source:2) 
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
2022-01-13 14:14:20.751 31043-28395/? E/AppCompatManager: setIncompatibleAppList exception:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: miui.security.appcompatibility.AppCompatibilityManager
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:379)
at com.miui.appcompatibility.b.c(Unknown Source:2)
at com.miui.appcompatibility.b.a(Unknown Source:29)
at com.miui.appcompatibility.b.a(Unknown Source:4)
at com.miui.appcompatibility.g.a$a.a(Unknown Source:12)
at com.miui.appcompatibility.g.a$a.doInBackground(Unknown Source:2)
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: miui.security.appcompatibility.AppCompatibilityManager
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454) 
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:379) 
at com.miui.appcompatibility.b.c(Unknown Source:2) 
at com.miui.appcompatibility.b.a(Unknown Source:29) 
at com.miui.appcompatibility.b.a(Unknown Source:4) 
at com.miui.appcompatibility.g.a$a.a(Unknown Source:12) 
at com.miui.appcompatibility.g.a$a.doInBackground(Unknown Source:2) 
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this issue while I was using Fleksy as default keyborad. Try using, Gboard or system keyboard as default.

Comment: I faced with the same issue based on user reports for Fleksy keyboard. while the text was wrapped into a `SelectionContainer` in composable function.
do you think is there a way to handle the crash somehow?

Comment: @imansdn I dont think so, i have tried multiple methods, on the app i was working on, nothing seemed to solve the proble. I think the issue is from Fleksy keyboard app itself